# Highchart ctor doesn't return a Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, initialization

When I create a chart using highstock.js  It doesn't return me a chart :

For example :

```
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    xAxis: {
        minRange: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

return the same like

```
var chart = $('#container');
```

To get the object I must redo the call to highcharts() method:

```
this.chart = $('#container').highcharts();
```

I don't understand really why and I'm afraid it creates two instances of highcharts object.

Here is a fiddle (see in js console) :

http://jsfiddle.net/ma15t0kx/2/

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't create 2 intances, is very typical in JS to access the object like this, in example you can access an instantiated jQuery UI Dialog like `$('#dialog').dialog('open')` you are accesing to the same instance

Comment: because you are chaining the instantiation with the jQuery selector, actually is like you were doing: var chart = $('#container'); chart.highcharts('StockChart', .... Is just the way jQuery works